# The Data Services Request version '3.0' is not supported in Fiori Application

Tags: request, odata, sapui5, payload, sap-fiori

I am extending a standard ODataService for SAP Sales Order create to custom service.

The Service request version is 2.0 for all request where the standard service is hit, but the point where the custom service is hit automatically the Service request version gets updated to **`DataServiceVersion 3.0`** and **`MaxDataServiceVersion 2.0`**.

Whenever I Place order I get below mentioned error.

`“The Data Services Request version '3.0' is not supported for the request payload.”`

Attached screenshot will show you the exact error and the request contents in details-

[image: Error screenshot]

**EDITED [23/01/2017]**

I know that ***SAP Gateway only supports OData version 2.0***.

***Similar issue-*** https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3689384 (However it is not helping in my case.)

Is there a way to update **`DataServiceVersion`** in the request manually.

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: hey,  I am also facing same issue and still struggling to solve this error..

Comment: @MahiKalyanar sure man, if you find anything related to this, feel free to update here...

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to call a different version of your service, please add a segment parameter to the URL as in the following example v=2
https://ldai1g1y.wdf.sap.corp:44356/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/....